# MIPS:what's instruction lui $1,4097 for?

Tags: mips

Original:

[image]

---

After Compact:

[image]

So how is the process of this? What is `lui` here for?

Answer (score 2):

`lui` is "Load upper immediate" and puts the the 16 bit immediate in the upper half of a register. In C-like notation `$r = imm16 << 16`. The register $1 is used as an assembler temporary. In this case the `lw` got divided into a `lui` and `lw` to load a full 32 bit address.

The instructions `li` and `la` are pseudo instructions ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set#Pseudo_instructions)) and they get replaced by a `lui` followed by a `ori`, `addiu` or `andi`.

Your assembler optimized the `lui` instructions away because the pseudo instructions and loads only need 16 bit values and addresses and not the full 32 bit values. Without optimization the assembler must assume that the full 32 bit values are needed.